# What is advantage of a longer TTL for DNS changes?

Tags: dns, ttl

A simple question from a DNS-neophyte:

What is the advantage of a longer TTL when making DNS changes? Wouldn't you want changes to take place as quickly as possible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records

Comment: In short, records that change less often should have a longer TTL, so that they are cached longer.